# An extension of line bundles splits locally

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Consider an extension $0\rightarrow L \overset{\alpha}{\rightarrow} E \overset{\beta}{\rightarrow} L' \rightarrow 0$ of bundles and bundle homomorphisms, where $L$ and $L'$ are line bundles. (Let's assume that all bundles and maps are holomorphic.)

Does it split locally? *i.e.* is there an open cover $\{U_i\}$ and maps $\sigma_i: L'\vert_{U_i} \rightarrow E\vert_{U_i}$ such that $\beta\circ \sigma_i = \text{id}$?

You could use a common trivialization for $L$, $L'$, and $E$, and then you get an extension of trivial bundles, say $0\rightarrow U\times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow U\times \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow U\times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow 0$. So a related question is: do extensions of trivial bundles split locally (or even globally)?

In the smooth case you can use a partition of unity to construct a Hermitian metric, and then you get splitting globally. I was hoping to get this local splitting for vector bundles in any setting, *i.e.* smooth, holomorphic, algebraic, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'll just shortly elaborate about the algebraic proof.
In fact line bundles are in one-to-one correspondence with locally free sheaves of rank 1.
They are locally given by projective modules (locally free = projective), and then the proof is just a simple algebraic fact that a surjection onto a projective modules splits, which is just the definition of projective.

Comment: We'll have a sequence of sheaves $0\rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}'\rightarrow 0$, and there's an open cover $\{U_i\}$ such that $\mathcal{F}\vert_{U_i} \simeq \mathcal{O}_X\vert_{U_i}$ and $\mathcal{F}'\vert_{U_i}\simeq \mathcal{O}_X\vert_{U_i}$ *as sheaves*.

The $\mathcal{F}'(V)$'s, for $V\subseteq U_i$, is free, so the stalk $\mathcal{F}'_p$ is projective for all $p\in U_i$, hence the extension splits at each stalk. That means it splits over all of $U_i$?

Comment: Don't argue with stalks, argue with restrictions. (Recall the definition of "locally free"!)

Comment: For affine schemes you may argue using projective modules. More generally you can argue like this locally: A locally trivial sheaf $E$ has an open cover $U_i$ where $E_{U_i}$ is trivial, hence projective. Hence local splittings exist.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, an extension $0 \to F \to E \to Q \to 0$ of holomorphic vector bundles splits locally (holomorphically, but not naturally) by your "common trivialization" argument: Pick a local holomorphic frame $\{e_{1},\dots,e_{n}\}$ for $E$ whose first $m$ elements span the fibre of $F$ at some point $p$. Extend to a local frame $\{f_{1},\dots,f_{m}\}$ for $F$, and note that there exist $mn$ (local) holomorphic functions $a_{jk}$ such that $f_{j} = \sum_{k} a_{jk} e_{k}$.

The elements $\{e_{m+1},\dots,e_{n}\}$ induce a frame of $Q$ provided the sum
$$
\operatorname{span}(f_{1},\dots,f_{m}) + \operatorname{span}(e_{m+1},\dots,e_{n})
$$
is direct. This is true in some neighborhood of $p$ by continuity of holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Given a complex manifold $X$ and two locally free sheaves (=vector bundles)  $\mathcal E, \mathcal G$ on $X$, the extensions $0\to \mathcal E\to   \mathcal F \to     \mathcal G    \to 0$ are classified by the complex vector space $H^1(X,\mathcal {Hom}(\mathcal G ,\mathcal E ))$.
The trivial extension $0\to \mathcal E\to   \mathcal E\oplus   \mathcal G\to     \mathcal G    \to 0$ corresponds to the zero element of that vector space.
In particular over  a Stein manifold all extensions are trivial (Theorem B of Cartan-Serre) and even more in particular all  extensions are trivial over a manifold isomorphic to a ball, for example the domain of a chart.
**Conclusion**
Yes, over holomorphic manifolds  all exact sequences of vector bundles split locally.
And the same proof, *mutatis mutandis*, shows that this also holds for differential manifolds, complex analytic spaces, algebraic varieties and schemes.
**Bibliography**
The classification of extensions mentioned above is Proposition 2 of Atiyah's seminal paper [Complex analytic connexions in fibre bundles.](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1957-085-01/S0002-9947-1957-0086359-5/S0002-9947-1957-0086359-5.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "In the smooth case you can use a partition of unity to construct a Hermitian metric, and then you get splitting globally. I was hoping to get this local splitting for vector bundles in any setting, i.e. smooth, holomorphic, algebraic, etc."

**Answer:** If $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is any ringed topological space and

$$\phi: E \rightarrow F \rightarrow 0$$

is a surjection of locally free sheaves on $X$ where $rk(E)=n, rk(F)=m$ and $m\leq n$
let $U_i$ be an open cover where $E,F$ trivialize and let

$$\phi_{U_i}:E_{U_i}\cong \mathcal{O}_{U_i}\{e_1,..,e_n\} \rightarrow F_{U_i}  \cong \mathcal{O}_{U_i}\{f_1,..,f_m\}$$

be the induced map. Choose $\omega_j\in E(U_i)$ with $\phi_{U_i}(\omega_j)=f_j$ and define for $V \subseteq U_i$

$$\psi_{U_i}(V): F(V) \rightarrow F(V)$$

by

$$\psi_{U_i}(V)(\sum_j  a_j f_j)=\sum_j (\omega_j)_{V}e_j.$$

It follows $\psi_{U_i}: F_{U_i}\rightarrow E_{U_i}$ is a local splitting of $\phi_{U_i}$. There is an equality

$$ \phi_{U_i} \circ \psi_{u_i}=Id_{F_{U_i}}.$$

Hence you can construct such local splitting for any ringed topological space $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$.